# uninitialized constant in controller -- constant is a class in my lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to use the delayed::job gem to delay when messages are sent, and when I try and run the code i get the error:

uninitialized constant RemindersController::RemindLater

The code I have in my controller is :

```
require 'delayed_job_active_record'
require 'delayed_job'

class RemindersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @reminder = Reminder.new
  end

  def create
    @reminder = Reminder.create(reminder_params)
    @reminder.user = current_user
    @reminder.save
    Delayed::Job.enque(RemindLater.new(@reminder.id), 0, @reminder.time) 
    redirect_to reminders_path
  end



  private
  def reminder_params
    params.fetch(:reminder, {}).permit(:text, :phone_number, :time, :picture, :favorite)
  end

end
```

in my /lib/remind_later.rb I have

```
class RemindLater < Struct.new(:reminder_id)

    def perform
        Reminder.send_text_message(reminder_id)
    end

end
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? thanks.

Comment: If you change `RemindLater` to `::RemindLater` what does that do?

Comment: I get the error 'uninitialized constant RemindLater'

Comment: Yeah, so it's not getting autoloaded. You're going to need to either create an initializer in config/initializers or put the path into `config.autoload_paths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you've added the lib directory the the `autoload_paths` in *config/application.rb*:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```